# Question marks instead of text when writing Persian with XePersian

Tags: xetex, xepersian

I am trying to write in Persian in TexShop(Mac) and keep getting question marks instead of my text. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\usepackage{bidi}
\settextfont{HM_XBNiloofar}
\title{چکیده}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
ساقیا
\end{document}
```

I am compiling it using XeLaTeX btw.

I remember being able to write in persian with my TexShop but now I cannot and I cannot find my old document to check it up.

Comment: Is it really this hard??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The encoding option should be set to UTF-8.

Comment: where did you set the encoding?